# Migration of Data Guard HW Servers to Cloud Servers

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, dataguard

I'm looking for information & advice on the best way to migrate from a hardware Oracle 19c Data Guard server pair to an Oracle 19c Cloud Data Guard server pair. Our configurations currently are:

### HW_Primary, HW_Standby

Currently Production DB

### Cloud_Primary, Cloud_Standby

Contains a Training DB.
Currently is in use for server configuration and remote site connectivity testing.

My plan at the moment is to:

- Break connection between HW_Primary & HW_Standby.
- Break connection between Cloud_Primary & Cloud_Standby.
  -Take a full backup of HW_Primary (DataPump or Level 0 Rman - preferences).
- Restore to Cloud_Primary .
- Bring up Cloud Primary for in-house data verification.
- Restore Cloud_Standby using Recover Standby database from service Cloud_Primary.
- Next would be backing up Cloud_Primary.
  (Side question: Is there a way to back up the Cloud_Standby while Dataguard is running?)
- And finally - Reverification of the data by remote sites.

I'm hoping this makes sense and will work. Please let me know what you think and feel free to make suggestions for improvement to this plan.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Have you tested the scenario outlined above with a small test database? Have you tried any other scenarios? What does our friend, Mr Google (or whoever your internet pal is) say about this? Your question is a bit broad for this forum - maybe try a couple of ways of doing what you want to do and get back to us with a more specific question. HTH.

Comment: I have been unable to find this scenario through Google and other searches.  As far as testing using a small DB, the difficulty in that is not having DG pairs just lying around.  In that area, my resources are limited.  And, TBH, I have been unable to come up with alternate solutions. I hoped that perhaps DBAs with more Data Guard experience would chime in.  In any case, I appreciate your response.  When I complete this task, I will respond here with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Leave on-premise primary and standby databases intact.
- Build 2nd standby in place of "cloud primary".
- Build 3rd standby in place of "cloud standby".
- Switchover to "cloud primary".

However, if you can afford all the downtime your method requires, just do whatever is the easiest for you.

Comment: I really like your scenario & solution.  Just to be sure I understand what your proposal is, please allow me to summarize.

I would treat the Cloud Prime as if it were a failover with no Flashback enabled and rebuild it in accordance with those procedures.  And, I would essentially do the same thing with the Cloud Standby.  When migration time comes around, I perform a switchover from HW Prime to Cloud Prime.  At some point, I would remove the HW servers from the configurations.  Is my understanding of your comments on target?